# Cordova iOS App Issue on Devices with iOS 16.4 and 16.5.1 using xcode 14.3

Tags: cordova-ios, xcode14.3

**Project Information:**

Cordova iOS platform: 5.1.1
macOS version: Ventura 13.5
Minimum target iOS version: 11.0
Xcode version: 14.3
SDK version: 16.4

**Plugins Used:**

cordova-background-geolocation-lt 3.0.4 "BackgroundGeolocation"

cordova-plugin-background-fetch 5.4.1 "CDVBackgroundFetch"

cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.8 "Badge"

cordova-plugin-barcodescanner 0.7.4 "BarcodeScanner"

cordova-plugin-camera 5.0.1 "Camera"

cordova-plugin-cocoalumberjack 0.0.4 "CocoaLumberjack"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"

cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"

cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.2 "Notification"

cordova-plugin-ios-camera-permissions 1.2.0 "iOS Permissions"

cordova-plugin-local-notification 0.9.0-beta.2 "LocalNotification"

cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.3 "StatusBar"

cordova-plugin-vibration 3.1.1 "Vibration"

cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"

phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 8.1.0 "BarcodeScanner"

**Issue:**
When building the Cordova app using Xcode 14.3, the app is successfully built and installed on various iOS devices. It functions as expected on devices running iOS 12.5.1, such as an iPod. However, an issue arises when attempting to install the app on an iPad running iOS 16.5.1. After installation, the app displays the splash screen and subsequently transitions to a black screen. Interestingly, the app functions properly on simulators like iPad mini (6th generation) with iOS 16.1, as well as on iOS 15.5 simulators. The problem specifically occurs on devices with iOS 16.4 and 16.5.1.

**Expected Outcome:**
The objective is to successfully install and run the Cordova app on devices running iOS versions 16.4 and 16.5.1, in a manner consistent with its performance on other iOS versions.

** What We tried** **

- we have update corodova ios platfrom 6.3.0
- select standard architecture arm64
- Build Active Architectures Only is Yes for Debug configurations, No for Release configurations